# ExpectedConditions can not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I am new to selenium and wanted to use Explicit wait with *chrome driver*.But I am not able to use ExpectedConditions class as it says *"org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions"* can not be resolved.Also I am not getting *until()* method in *WebDriverWait* class.Have shared the code and pom file I am using.Please guide where I am going wrong.

**Selenium Script**

```
package seleniumutils;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ById;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;//Error at this line 


public class SeleniumUtils {

    WebDriver driver;
    final String webUrl = "url";
    final String pathToChromeDriver = "path to chromedriver.exe";
    final String KEY_WEB_DRIVER = "webdriver.chrome.driver";
    WebDriverWait wait;

    public void initDriver() {
        System.setProperty(KEY_WEB_DRIVER, pathToChromeDriver);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(webUrl);
        //         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String str = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("The current URL is " + str);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    }


    public List < WebElement > getElementsByID(String id) {
        List < WebElement > list = (List < WebElement > ) driver.findElement(ById.id(id));
        return list;
    }

    public void waitForScanner(String lookup) {

        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(driver.findElement(By.xpath(lookup))));
    }
```

**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.interact-ez</groupId>
    <artifactId>interact-ez</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>interact-ez</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**SCREENSHOTS**
[image: Error while importing]
[image: Until method is not visible]

Comment: I do not see an import for org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.* ?

Comment: That's the problem I am facing.It gives error ExpectedConditions can not be resolved.This error comes while importing the package only.

Comment: What happens if you remove the "ExpectedConditions" part at the end and just use a *?

Comment: Then remove from import disappears but still error at linewhere I am using ExpectedConditions with message "ExpectedConditions  can not be resolved ".

Comment: Check the selenium jar if it is complete and has this class... Download it again

Comment: I checked.It has that class.I tried with different versions.But no success yet

Comment: Ok so I have  changed version to 3.0.1 and everything working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing says it all :

```
"org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions" can not be resolved
```

It is clear from your published code you have missed out to include the following **imports** :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

Finally, you have tried the **ExpectedConditions** as :

```
until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(driver.findElement(By.xpath(lookup))));
```

If you look at the `JavaDocs` of the [**`ExpectedConditions`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as [**`visibilityOfElementLocated`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) the method clearly accepts the parameter [**`By locator`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) where as you have passed [**`WebElement element`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) which is as follows :

```
visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)
An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible.
```

### Solution

The solution will be to :

- Add the required **import** :

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  ```
- Change the call to `visibilityOfElementLocated` as :

  ```
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(lookup)));
  ```

Comment: Please check updated comment in code.Also when I press ctrl+space to check availble methods after wait object I dont see until method in list.

Comment: Clean the project from your `IDE`, use `CCleaner` to wipe away all the OS chores and do `mvn clean`, `mvn install` and `mvn test`

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency to your pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and Go to your project-->Maven-->update